# List fields in R do not match

Tags: r

I'm not a great R expert but recently for university reasons I had to use the "ltm" package, I have no problems with some particular function but when I call it one that should return a list and then i get one of the values it is different from those shown before.
it's simpler if I show it to you.

```
install.packages("ltm")
library("ltm")
x <- rasch(LSAT)
coeff <- x$coefficients
```

Content of x

```
Call:
rasch(data = LSAT)

Coefficients:
Dffclt.Item 1  Dffclt.Item 2  Dffclt.Item 3  Dffclt.Item 4  Dffclt.Item 5  
   -3.615         -1.322         -0.318         -1.730         -2.780  
   Dscrmn  
    0.755  

Log.Lik: -2466.938
```

Content of coeff :

```
           beta.i   beta
Item 1  2.7300133   0.7551347
Item 2  0.9986059   0.7551347
Item 3  0.2398539   0.7551347
Item 4  1.3064513   0.7551347
Item 5  2.0994042   0.7551347
```

The second column "beta" is correct, it's just the Dscrmn value repeated for the length of the table but why the elements in the column "beta.i" are not the same as "Dffclt.Item 1  Dffclt.Item 2  Dffclt.Item 3  Dffclt.Item 4  Dffclt.Item 5"

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `coef(x)` is the proper interface for an object of class "rasch" according to the docs, I guess. You can read `coef.rasch` to see what the difference is between that and the internal thing you get with `$coef`.

Comment: It works, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`coef(x)` is the proper interface for an object of class "rasch" according to the docs. You can read the function `coef.rasch` to see what the difference is between that and the internal component you get with `$coef`:

```
> ltm::coef.rasch
function (object, prob = FALSE, order = FALSE, ...) 
{
    if (!inherits(object, "rasch")) 
        stop("Use only with 'rasch' objects.\n")
    cof <- if (object$IRT.param) {
        coefs <- IRT.parm(object)$parms
        p <- length(coefs)
        matrix(c(coefs[1:(p - 1)], rep(coefs[p], p - 1)), ncol = 2, 
            dimnames = list(colnames(object$X), c("Dffclt", "Dscrmn")))
    }
    else {
        object$coef
    }
    if (prob) 
        cof <- cbind(cof, `P(x=1|z=0)` = plogis(object$coef[, 
            1]))
    if (order) 
        cof <- cof[order(cof[, 1]), ]
    cof
}
<environment: namespace:ltm>
```

So the key toggle is whether IRT parameters are used (`TRUE` by default). Following the docs...

> If `IRT.param = TRUE`, then the parameters estimates are reported under the usual IRT parameterization, i.e.,
>
> *logit (π_i) = beta (z - beta_i^*)*.

Comment: I have just [learnt](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/320674/constraining-item-difficulty-in-2pl-estimation-using-ltm) that (1) the argument `IRT.param` by default is not set at all and (2) that it only affects the reporting of parameter estimates (e.g. `coef`, `print`, `summary`). During the estimation process the parameter is then set to `TRUE` if there is a single (non-exponentiated) latent variable  (e.g. in the rasch case).